# Three.js Autocomplete in Visual Studio Code

Tags: autocomplete, three.js

I have been working through Mozilla game development docs. I am now onto the task of using my first 3D Javascript framework. It is called Three.js. The problem I now face is that my Visual Studio Code won't autocomplete this new syntax. I am using

Please help me get autocomplete to work.

Answer (score 2):

When you develop in TypeScript, try to install the definition module: [types/three](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/three)

It installs all definitions of used methods.

You can install it with `npm install --save @types/three`

Comment: I am not developing in TypeScript. I am developing in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

And when you develop in Javascript, simply add a reference to the three library:

put this at the beginning of your code `/// <reference path='js/three.js' />`

read [this](https://madskristensen.net/blog/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) article for more information.

Comment: I'm a newbie: beginning after the <script> tags?